# Array driver class Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, driver

Hey guys I'm having problems figuring out how to write my driver class for my Array class.

My questions

1.How do I make the array in my Array class reference the array in my Driver class?

2.How do I pass my class methods from my Array class to my Driver class so I can print them out?

Here's my two bits of code

Main class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Array
{

    double sum = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int min = numbers[0];
    double sd = 0;
    int mode = 0;
    int modeCount = 0;
    public double average()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + numbers[i];
        }

        double average = sum / numbers.length;
        return average;
    }

    public int max()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
        {
            if(numbers[i] > max)
            {
                max = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    public int min()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
        {
            if(numbers[i] < min)
            {
                min = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return min;
    }

    public double standardDeviation()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<numbers.length;i++)
        {
            sum = sum + numbers[i];
            double average = sum / numbers.length;
            {
                sd += ((numbers[i] - average)*(numbers[i] - average)) / (numbers.length - 1);
            }
        }
        double standardDeviation = Math.sqrt(sd);
        return standardDeviation;
    }

    public int mode()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) 
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; ++j) 
            {
                if (numbers[j] == numbers[i]) ++count;
            }
            if (count > modeCount) {
                modeCount = count;
                mode = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return mode;
    }
}
```

Driver class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayTest
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int[] numbers;
        numbers = new int [20];
        Random rand = new Random(2621); 
        int maxRange = 65;
        int minRange = 20;

        for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = rand.nextInt(maxRange - minRange + 1) + minRange;       
        }

        Arrays.sort(numbers);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to apply your array methods to certain array then your methods should receive an array as a parameter in the Array class or you can define an instance array inside the class which is set in the constructor, for example.

Comment: ok so I believe I did that I passed in (int [] numbers) into each of my methods in my Arrays class, I still do not understand how to call/print out these methods from my driver class...

Comment: Since the methods in your class are not static you first have to instantiate an instance of your class Array a = new Array(); a.mode();. Had you declared your methods as static methods you would be able to call it as the Arrays class i.e Arrays.sort().

Answer (score 0):

Looks a lot like a homework assignment...

In your `Array` class, you can keep a reference to the array and then have a method called `setArray()` that you can use to pass the array from your main class to your Array class.

```
int[] numbers;

public void setArray(int[] nums) {
    numbers = nums;
}
```

then from your main class you can call

```
Array.setArray(myIntArray);
int max = Array.max();
```

In real life (other than for programming practice), you would never want to do this though.